# Which parse method scrapy used to parse start_urls

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want scrapy to scrape some start urls and then follow the links in those pages according to rules. My spider is inherited from `CrawlSpider` and has `start_urls` and 'rules' set. But it doesn't seems to use the parse function I defines to parse the start_urls. Here are the codes:

```
<!-- language: lang-python --> 
class ZhihuSpider(CrawlSpider):

    start_urls = ["https://www.zhihu.com/topic/19778317/organize/entire",
        "https://www.zhihu.com/topic/19778287/organize/entire"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow= (r'topic/\d+/organize/entire')), \
            process_request='request_tagInfoPage', callback = 'parse_tagPage'))

    # this is the parse_tagPage() scrapy should use to scrape
    def parse_tagPage():
        print("start scraping!") # Explicitly print to show that scraping starts
        # do_something
```

However, the console shows that scrapy crawled start_urls but nothing printed. So I am pretty sure that the parse_tagPage() function isn't called. Even though, scrapy shows that the urls is crawled `[scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.zhihu.com/topic/19778317/organize/entire> (referer: http://www.zhihu.com)`

Any hints on why this would happen and how to set scrapy to use parse_tagPage()?

Comment: you should read up the documentation, when you mention start_urls , scrapy will visit that url with start_request() method and then will see if it matches the rules you mentioned , if it matches the rule , it will visit parse_tagPage() method else will do nothing ( you can define default callback method when no rule is matched)

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=start%20request#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests

Comment: You can answer your own question, and then accept your answer instead of editing the question with the answer.

Comment: Thanks Burhan! Didn't know that.

Comment: @MrPandav I know that. I already ruled out it because I overrided the start_requests() method to get a hidden parameter and cookie to pass the anti-bot mechanism. Part of the reason parse_tagPage() wasn't called is that the CrawlSpider class uses parse() function on ALL request without a callback function assigned. which isn't in the documentation.

Comment: @skywalker326 ah ! great that you have figured it out and it is documented here[1] that parse is default method for crawlspider and one should not override it [1]http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules

Comment: Hi, I am stuck at a position which is more or less the same. So, my rule extractor extracts some href ("abcd") but I want request to be sent at baseUrl+"abcd". Like fb.com/abcd. How can I achieve that? I think I need to manipulate 'process_request' parameter but I am unable to think of how to achieve that. Since, href is being found, I can't use callback.

Comment: I also tried to override the parse method, but failed to get the href there. I guess, it's because of the reason Skywalker is mentioning in point 1 of his answer. This is my first day with Scrapy and am stuck this bad.

Answer (score 0):

1st, the CrawlSpider class uses a default parse() method to deal with ALL requests that doesn't specifies a callback function, in my case including the requests made from start_urls. This parse() method only applies rules to extract links and doesn't parse the pages of start_url at all. That's why I can't scrape anything from the start_url pages.

2nd, the LinkExtractor somehow only extracts the first links from start_urls pages. And unfortunately, the first links are start_urls themselves. So the scrapy internal duplication-preventing mechanism blocks parsing those pages. That's why the callback function parse_tagPage() is called.

I am working on fixing the LinkExtractor.

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite parse_start_url() that to parse start_urls

Comment: You should also add some explanation of the answer, see how do I write a good answer [answer].